# Is there a way with sass to change a button's background-color depending on its parent's background-color?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, sass

I'm currently writing a complete css library for a new project.

At the moment I'm stuck with something I want to achieve but I'm starting to doubt it is even possible.

We've got a few different button types. One of these types is a button but with two possible background colors (grayish if on a white bg; whitish if on a gray bg)
I could just add another class to the button to specify if the bg needs to be gray but I wouldn't prefer that because think there might be a much nicer solution (I also think this could cause problems later on when we allow our users to choose from a dark or a light theme on our platform).

I also tried fixing it by reaching out to the ancestors to check if there was a class on them specifying the darker bg (eg. .container-dark)...
This does work as long as I don't put the button in a container with a white bg whitin the container with a gray bg. At this moment the css will still find the ancestor with the class .container-dark and thus will give the button a white bg eventhough it is within a white container....

I also though about about setting background-color equal to 'inherit' and then use a function with an if/else but I can't figure out how to access the buttons background-color (which it has inherited at that moment)....

If you know wether or not this is even possible, please let me know and any ideas are welcome!

kind regards

Comment: You should add some code as an example. Hard to tell without that.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible.

Comment: with using SASS, i would personnally use a variable for this. Imagine in your stylesheet buttons have a `background-color: $button-bg-color;`, all you would need is to have the variable set to the right color to set any theme you like, basically creating themes by only seeting these variables value

Comment: What if you just made the button's background semi-transparent? Something like `background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.5)`

Comment: @Blazemonger — That would only work if you wanted to make the background a darker shade of the parent element. You can't use a translucency to make an element white when the background is grey.

Comment: To be clearer about what i was trying to express, it's probably pointless to go for a "all-dynamic detection/adaptation" here, as with the increased complexity will also come rigidity for future style evolutions. Maybe better if you want to mix dark and light content/buttons, to define variables for colors of primary zones content/buttons, and a secondary set of color variables for secondary zones that have different background/buttons.. IMO it's more simple and flexible

Comment: Without code is difficult to understand how can works but f you have a container to define the background (.container-dark) you can change the button color simply `.container-dark button {background-color:#fff}` while the standard button have another color `button {background-color:ddd}`

Comment: @GermanoPlebani that's sort of a method I tried but it doesn't work if you have a button in a dark-container but for some reason the button is in a field with a white background inside this container)
As I have stated to my colleagues I still think it's best to have this button type have a default bg color of white for example and give it another class when I know it's supposed to be grey...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. SASS deals only with the generation of CSS.

Since the background colour of the parent element is determined by the application of the CSS to a DOM at runtime, SASS can't calculate it. It doesn't run late enough.

You would need to use client-side JS to solve this problem.

Comment: I actually didn't think about this (still quite new to development).
Will I also be able to do this if I don't knew how many ancestors my button will have before a specific color is set? 
I mean... the button might be inside a few other tags that have no specific background color set and thus have a background color of transparent or inherit?

Comment: @Stoffel — You can recursively test the computed style of `.parentNode` until you get a real colour. Watch out for background images.